# Prove that for all $\phi, \psi \in M$, $S(\phi \circ \psi) = S(\phi) S(\psi)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, group-theory

**Problem:**
Let $[n] = \{1,2, \dots, n\}$. We define $M$ to be the set of bijections $\phi : [n] \rightarrow [n]$, and $S: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

The map $S(\phi) = \prod_{i>j=1}^n \dfrac{\phi(i) - \phi(j)}{i-j}$.

I must prove that $S(\phi\psi) = S(\phi)S(\psi)$

---

I've tried defining $S(\phi)$ and $S(\psi)$ and multiplying them together to see if I can get something of the form $S(\phi\psi)$, but I'm having big issues with the $\Pi$ symbol. I would like some hints, or if this problem looks familiar in terms of $S$, some general direction.

Edit: Perhaps, is the range of this function $\{1, -1\}$ and how would I go about showing that, if so? I suppose there's a proof by contradiction approach?

Comment: Is $\phi \psi$ meant as composition or pointwise multiplication?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation

Comment: You can begin by showing a direct equivalent definition of  $S$,  that is $$S(\phi) = \prod_{ \text{ pair }(i,j)\\ \text{ such that }1\le i ,j \le n ; i \ne j  } \dfrac{\phi(i)-\phi(j)}{i-j}  $$

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen I don't think it is. For $\phi = (1\,2)$ we get $$S(\phi) = \frac{\phi(1)-\phi(2)}{1-2}\cdot \frac{\phi(2)-\phi(1)}{2-1} = (-1)\cdot (-1) = 1$$
and it should be $-1$. The point is that if $i \ne j$, we can take $(i,j)$ or $(j,i)$ in the definition of $S$.

Comment: @mechanodroid: This a product by unordered pair. Not tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$S(\phi\psi) = \prod_{i > j} \frac{\phi(\psi(i)) - \phi(\psi(j))}{i-j} = \prod_{i > j} \frac{\phi(\psi(i)) - \phi(\psi(j))}{\psi(i)-\psi(j)} \cdot \prod_{i > j} \frac{\psi(i)-\psi(j)}{i-j} = S(\phi)S(\psi)$$

Indeed, we have
$$\prod_{i > j} \frac{\phi(\psi(i)) - \phi(\psi(j))}{\psi(i)-\psi(j)} = \prod_{i>j} \frac{\phi(i)-\phi(j)}{i-j}$$
because $\psi$ is a bijection. If $\psi(i)>\psi(j)$ then leave the term as it is, and if $\psi(i)<\psi(j)$ we use the fact that
$$\frac{\phi(\psi(i)) - \phi(\psi(j))}{\psi(i)-\psi(j)} = \frac{\phi(\psi(j)) - \phi(\psi(i))}{\psi(j)-\psi(i)}.$$

Comment: I missed that $\psi$ is a bijection! The rest falls out!